# Merging a lot of CSV files in R?

Tags: r

I have 111 .csv files, each around 50 MB in size. The files all have the same columns. I need to merge them all into one file. I'm running the following code:

```
list.files() %>% 
  map(read_csv) %>% 
  reduce(bind_rows) -> data
```

However, I'm getting the following error:

```
Error: cannot allocate vector of size 137.9 Mb
```

This is very weird to me because I have 16 GB of RAM; when I enter the `memory.limit()` command, it outputs `16316`, which should be more than enough. All 111 files take up around 5.6 GB on the disk so it shouldn't be a problem.

What can I do to merge these files?

Comment: Try using `data.table` i.e `data <- rbindlist(lapply(list.files(), fread))`

Comment: Unfortunately not working, `Error: cannot allocate vector of size 420.2 Mb`

Comment: This seems a complicated way of doing something relatively simple.  You may have an unexpectedly complicated list structure.  Try `bind_rows(lapply(list.files(), read.csv))`. [Similar to @RonakShah]

Comment: You ran out of RAM. 5.6 GB on disk will exceed your RAM limit, break your loop in couple parts, or try to append csv without loading all of the content in R.

Comment: @Limey This produces the same error as above

Comment: @JacobJacox Just to check if I understood correctly - I should merge, let's say 37 files into Intermediate file 1, next 37 into intermediate file 2 and the last 37 into intermediate file 3. Then I should merge these 3 files into one file? But doesn't that take up the same space as this operation?

Comment: The file itself may be 5 gb, but due to file compression it could be taking up say 8 gb in memory. In addition `R` on windows has a rumour for capping your available memory at launch (although i have not been able to find a reproducible example of this). What Ronak and Jacob is suggesting is to load and process the files individually. Alternatively certain packages such as [biglm](https://cran.r-project.org/package=biglm) can help out with 'on-desk' operations rather than 'in-memory'. (Many packages on cran named big*** can help with this).

Comment: In addition you might have other processes taking up quite a large amount of memory. On windows you can see this using the `task manager`. Alternatively you can see the available memory (windows only) using `memory.limit()` within R.

Comment: I was thinking merge them into 3 big files, then join the second one to 1st one without loading 1st one into RAM (and R). I m not sure if data.table does that but there are some packages meant for big data that do not load all the data into the RAM.

Comment: BTW if you are on Windows, and do not care about time efficiency, just increase virtual ram with `memory.limit(100000)` and when R will ran out of RAM, it will use SSD to store data. It will be slow but it wont crash, for one time job its fine.

Comment: @J.Doe What are `dim`ensions of an average .csv data set?

Comment: If you just want to combine them in a new file, it is not necessary to have all data in memory at the same time. Just read them with `readLines` line by line and then write it out with `cat( ..., file=outfile, append=TRUE)`, except the additional caption lines. It may be slow, so as a compromise one may also read in complete files one after the other and then append it to the output file. As an alternative, you may also consider to output the data to a sql data base or a netcdf file.